# c++ inheritance : confused with base member access from derived object

Tags: c++, inheritance, radix, derived

Declaration:

```
class base{
public:
    base(){a=0;}
    base(int a);
    int getA();
    virtual ~base() ;
protected:
    int a ;
};
//
class derived : public base {
public:
    derived(){}
    derived(int a, int b) ;
    int getC() ;
    ~derived();
private:
    int c ;
};
```

Definition :

```
base::base(int a){
    cout << "   in base constructor a = " << a << endl ;
    a = a ;
}
base::~base(){
    a = 0 ;
}
int base::getA(){
    return a ;
}
//
derived::derived(int a, int b)
:base(a)
{
    c = a+b ;
}
int derived::getC()
{
    return c ;
}
derived::~derived(){
    c = 0 ;
}
```

Call:

```
derived A(4,5) ;
cout << "   a of A = " << A.getA() << "\n" ;
cout << "   c of A = " << A.getC() << "\n" ;
```

Result :

```
in base constructor a = 4
a of A = 4205648
c of A = 9
```

Please can someone explain why I am getting this result instead of :

```
a of A = 4
```

? Why does the value of base member a change ? Based on what I've learned about inheritance in c++, when we create an object of derived class, this object will inherit all members and member functions of base class, why is it that the member a of object `A` of class derived loses its value outside the derived class definition ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
base::base(int a){
    cout << "   in base constructor a = " << a << endl ;
    a = a ;
}
```

This line changes the value of constructor parameter `a`, not the value of `a` of `base`. Better will be

```
base::base(int _a){
    cout << "   in base constructor a = " << _a << endl ;
    a = _a ;
}
```

And even better is to use constructor initialization list:

```
base::base(int _a): a(_a) {
    cout << "   in base constructor a = " << a << endl ;
}
```

In the latter case you can even write

```
base::base(int a): a(a) {
    cout << "   in base constructor a = " << a << endl ;
}
```

because in the initialization list there is no ambiguity, although I still prefer to be explicit and use different names for constructor parameters and class members.

Comment: The real solution would be to use the constructor initialization list, so maybe that one should go first.

Comment: @juanchopanza which is used in the last example of the answer, no?

Comment: @juanchopanza , I tried to show how one can gradually improve the solution, and I think the wording makes it clear which is better.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's smart to put the best (or *real* as you put it) solution in the conclusion which has the best chances of staying in memory of the reader.

Comment: Thanks Petr and all for your answers. I still do not understand why this line does not work :base::base(int a){
    cout << "   in base constructor a = " << a << endl ;
    a = a ;
} ... Shouldn't the compiler understand that the first a in "a = a" is the base class member and the second a is the constructor parameter ??

Comment: @lounice Yes, the compiler can figure that out...in the initialization list.  OP does not have initialization of `this->a` in the initialization list.  If OP insists on keeping `a = a;` in the body of the constructor, then preface the first `a` with the `this` pointer: `this->a = a;`.

Comment: @Iounice "Shouldn't the compiler understand that the first a in "a = a" is the base class member and the second a is the constructor parameter ??" — no, it shouldn't. Why do you think it should?